# Limit the number of words in a response with a regular expression

Tags: regex

Does anybody have a regular expression that would work to limit the number of words in a response? For instance, I'd like to use it with jQuery validate so I can restrict a textbox/textarea to have say 250 words. The boxes will be plain-text.

I've done some Googling but none of the ones I've found were very good. They mostly centered around doing \b\w+\b but I had trouble getting it work.

Comment: It might make more sense to count characters - there's nothing stopping people from just typing and typing and typing with no spaces...that said, VonC's answer looks excellent!

Comment: What about punctuation? Are requiring your users to type in only word characters and whitespace?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you try:

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,250}$
```

That would limit to 250 words over multiple lines.

I am afraid that the Alan's initial proposition:

```
/^\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,249}$/
```

might be a case of [**catastrophic backtracking**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

> When nesting repetition operators, make absolutely sure that there is only one way to match the same match

---

To allow for basic punctuation, see [janksmap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13537464/janksmap)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73901130/6309).

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n\.\,\?\!]*){0,250}$
```

---

For non-Latin script (like Hebrew), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77874502/6309).

Comment: This seemed to work in my tests. I'm not sure if this version has any downsides but I'm going to accept this one for now.

Comment: This works for me except if I enter " , @ it returns false. Can you tell me what I need to do ? Thanks

Comment: @iOSAppDev word boundaries (http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) depend on the regex flavor you are using. If simply adding the quotes as a separator in my original regex (ie: `^(?:\b\w+\b["\s\r\n]*){1,250}$`) doesn't work, then it is best to look at alternative solution (meaning "beside regex").

Comment: Thanks for link. Can you suggest any alternative solution ? I want to restrict user to enter max 150 words in textview. User can enter anything or copy & paste in text box.

Comment: @iOSAppDev not on the top of my head, but that would be a good question to ask (with a link back to this one, and with lots of details about the error you got and why it doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks VonC. I will ask a new question with link to this question

Comment: I have added separate question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515131/restrict-the-user-to-enter-max-50-words-in-uitextview-ios

Comment: how to ignore space at the end? "a "is invalid while "a a" is valid

Answer (score 3):

How about splitting the text with a regex (say "\s+") and then counting the length of the resulting list? That would be somewhat easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

This has worked well for me, for example if you want a 6-word limit:

```
^(?:\w+\W+){0,5}(?:\w+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand VonC's response, I found that by slightly modifying it, you can allow for basic punctuation and anywhere from 0 to 250 words.

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n\.\,\?\!]*){0,250}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regular expression I use for the word count validation.

```
(\w*\W*){0,250}
```

Comment: this worked for me even when i add comma(,) for number of words defined we are looking at in specified text field.

Comment: How to add for the above statement that it should accept space only and null along with above expression

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
^\W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,250}$
```

Comment: This worked better than the accepted answer for me. I modified it to treat periods and commas as word characters, which is helpful when someone enters numbers or domain names, and mirrors the way Word counts words. ^\W*(?:[\w\.\,]+(?:\W+|$)){1,250}$