# Limit the number of words with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

The regular expression which you gave: `^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,250}$`
to limit 250 words over multiple lines works if it doesn't have any special characters.

What should I do if I need to search for number of words which also consists special characters? Something like this an example:

```
--> Hi! i need help with regular expression, please help me. <--
```

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557695/limit-the-number-of-words-in-a-response-with-a-regular-expression ?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach is to group the word characters, and limit those groups to a specific range (1-250):

```
^\W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,250}$
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with C# so I will describe the regex.

**Method 1:**

You are basically looking for this:

```
(\b[^\s]+\b){1,250}
```

In java:

`\s`  is any whitespace character.

`[^\s]+`  is a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

`\b` is a word boundary.

You can translate the regex to C#.

**Method 2:**

Tokenize the input text into whitespace delimited words. In java, this is done by:

```
String[] tokens = inputString.split("\\s+");
```

where the regex is `\s+`

Now you can count the length of the array and implement your logic to reject the words beyond 250.

**Method 3:**

Define a pattern to capture whitespace as a 'capturing group'.

```
(\s+)
```

Now you can do a count the number of matches in your pattern matcher using a while loop. This is essentially kinda same as Method 2 but without involving the creation of the array of tokens.

Comment: [^\s]+ can be replaced with \S+

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer but none of the solutions here worked:

^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9]*){1,8}$

where {1,8} defines how many wordt you want

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why Justen Ludwig's didn't work? I tried in a jsfiddle and works well for me, but if you have a test case that fails it would be very helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/7PKW7/

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me too. I'm using it in Umbraco. And just in case someone wants it, here's the modified version which includes symbols: ^([^\s]*[\s]*){1,8}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{a,b}` quantifiers on any expression, like so:

```
.{1,256}
[\d\w_?]{1,567}
(0x)?[0-9A-F]{1,}
```

So, in your case, you could use:

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[_!?\s\r\n]*){1,250}$
```

Where the `_!?` can be any special characters.