# What is the best way to get the first x number of words from a string javascript

Tags: javascript

With out using jquery, what is the easiest way to do this? If I have a string containing 600 words, and I want only the first 100 or so words and then trail off with: `...` what is the easiest way to do this?

I found: `replace(/(([^\s]+\s\s*){40})(.*)/,"$1…");` But I don' understand regex enough to know if this is right or not.

Comment: Did you test that code?

Comment: `str.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 100).join(' ') + '...'`

Comment: @dfsq, that's slicing on spaces, shouldn't it be better to be counting words by using word bounderies?

Comment: @Mouser strictly speaking that would cause trouble with hyphenated words. I don't think the exactness of 40 is of utmost importance, but I would think it's nicer not to break off in the midst of a hyphenated word which you happen with word bounderies.

Comment: `^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,100}$` (credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557695/limit-the-number-of-words-in-a-response-with-a-regular-expression )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@dfsq's solution is a nice straight forward one, but in the interest of learning :)

To try and understand regexes, I would advice looking at the flow-chart-alike visualisation that **[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6oeuiTgeAz_d4fpr)** gives you, and experiment with substitution on **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zT2oV4/1)**. *(links contain the regex unaltered from your question)*

I would make some small modifications:

1. The `.` doesn't match new-lines, one way to do that is to match `[\s\S]` in stead, which matches absolutely every character
2. This: `[^\s]+\s\s*` can be untangled and optimized to `\S+\s+`, but I would turn it around and make it `\s*\S+` so that the `...` comes after the last word without a space in between.

Which would result in this:

```
((\s*\S+){40})([\s\S]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 substitution in action](https://regex101.com/r/zT2oV4/2)

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple I guess (I don't know if this is the best way) !

```
for(var i=1;i <= numberOfWords;i++) {
    var word = mystr.substr(0,mystr.indexOf(' ')+1).trim();
    arrayOfWords.push(word);
    mystr = mystr.substr(mystr.indexOf(' '),mystr.length-1).trim();
}
```

Try for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/fourat05/w386mxaa/